# Solutions depending continuously on the initial condition do not imply a non-chaotic state?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

In Glendinning's book *Stability, Instability and Chaos* (theorem 1.2), he said that if in the ode $\dot x = f(x,t)$, $f$ is smooth near $(0,0)$, and the initial condition $x(0)\in(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, then solutions $x(t)$ exist and depend continuously on the initial condition $x(0)$.

This statement seems to negate the possibility of chaos (i.e. solutions being sensitive to $x(0)$) for such an ode. But the author says it is not so, because 'solutions are' not necessarily 'uniformly continuous in both variables...space and time' $x(0), t$, 'double limits can be tricky.'

The author seems to say the reason is that $f$ is not necessarily continuous in (x(0),t). For example, for $\dot x = x$, $x(C,t) = C e^t$, even if this function is continuous on $C$ and on $t$, it may not be a continuous function of $(C,t)$ , respectively. (This is perhaps not a proper example. But I hope the readers see my point here.) But the author's explanation is fairly sketchy. How to explain the possibility of chaos for such a function, in detail?

Comment: Just think of any chaotic example that you like, say the Lorenz attractor, and convince yourself that it actually **has** continuous dependence on initial conditions.

Comment: @HansLundmark For a pinball machine, when t is small, the position x(t) does not vary much if x(0) does not. Only when t is large, to guarantee a small variation of x(t), must the variation of t be impractically tiny. So x(t) depends continuously on t, but *not uniformly when t is small and t is large.* Climate prediction is another example.$\quad$ Another one is $x_{n+1} = 10 x_n (mod 1),$ if the variation of $x_0$ is sufficiently small, then for a sufficiently large range of n, the variance of $x_n$ is 0. The large variance and unpredictability only when n exceeds $-\log_{10}\delta x_0$.

Comment: Chaos is sensitivity (it can belong to non-uniform continuity), not discontinuity. And uniform continuity is that the same $\delta y$ at different t requires (infinitely) different $\delta t$.